# Como hacer pull de una versión vieja

Tags: git, github, vscode

Estoy empezando a usar git para guardar mis proyectos en la nube y quería saber cómo puedo hacer un pull después de haber hecho unos cambios que no quería hacer.

Estaba modificando un archivo y la he liado, quería coger la versión vieja de github pero cuando hago `git pull` me dice **alredy up to date**, si hago `git status` me dice **your branch is ahead of master by 1 commit**.

¿Cómo puedo obtener los archivos del repositorio remoto aunque sean viejos?

Comment: Puedes hacer un reset git checkout master y luego usando el SHA-1 del commit al que deseas regresar git reset <sha-1> o simplemente un ckekout a el commit git checkout <sha-1>.

Comment: Disculpa, ¿Qué? ¿Que es el SHA-1? ¿Qué hace git reset?

Comment: SHA-1 me refiero a el identificador del registro del commit https://lostechies.com/content/joshuaflanagan/uploads/2011/03/gitkgitkdemo_20100903_123037_2639A187.png

Comment: Prueba: git branch test, git checkout test, git pull. Cada una son líneas distintas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Primero algunos conceptos

Git es un sistema de control de versiones *distribuido*, lo que quiere decir que a diferencia de otros sistemas el histórico no está guardado en un solo lugar (en la nube), sino que está en cada uno de los sitios en que lo usas. La copia de la nube no es diferente de la copia que tienes en tu propio ordenador. Ambas contienen la historia de commits completa.

Lo único que hace `git pull` es traer a tu ordenador las partes de la historia que estuvieran en la nube, pero no en tu ordenador (típicamente porque colaboras con otros programadores y alguno de ellos ha subido commits nuevos a la nube). Entiendo que en tu caso eres la única persona trabajando sobre el repositorio, por lo que no hay en la nube commits nuevos que tú no tengas en tu copia local, y por eso el mensaje de que "already up to date".

En realidad tienes el caso contrario, tu historia local tiene un commit más que la historia guardada en la nube (y de ahí el mensaje "your branch is ahead of master by 1 commit".

De modo que lo que quieres en realidad no es hacer un pull, sino **eliminar el último commit que has hecho**, lo cual en la situación actual es sencillo porque ese commit sólo está en tu versión local. Si lo hubieras subido con `push` sería más complicado ya que tendría que eliminarlo también de la copia "en la nube" (y peor aún, si colaborabas con otros y los demás habían hecho `pull` tendrías que eliminarlo también de cada una de las otras copias locales de tus colaboradores).

## La solución

Para "eliminar" un commit lo que tienes que hacer en realidad es hacer retroceder la cabeza de tu rama ("HEAD") al commit anterior. Esto se logra con el comando:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Lo de `HEAD~1` significa "el commit anterior al último realizado. Esto no sólo afecta a la historia local (de la cual desaparecerá el último commit), sino también a tu carpeta local gracias a la opción `--hard`. Con esa opción, la carpeta de trabajo será restaurada también al estado en que estaba en el commit anterior (que será por tanto el estado que puedes ver en tu repositorio en la nube, a través de su interfaz web).

Sin la opción `--hard` la carpeta de trabajo no sería modificada (el historial `git` retrocedería al commit anterior, pero los cambios que hubiera en la carpeta seguirían en ella, de modo que `git status` te diría que tienes cambios sin guardar).

En cualquiera de los dos casos, al haber eliminado el último commit de tu histórico local, éste ya coincidirá con el de la nube, por lo que ya no te dirá lo de "your branch is ahead of master by 1 commit."